# SSH C# & Cisco devices configuration download

Tags: c#, ssh, cisco

I'm trying to write some software in C# VS which is going to be used to connect through SSH to network devices ( Cisco Switches / Routers ) and download their configuration periodically. I've already tried SharpSSH, SSH.NET. The former is outdated and bugged, the latter just spams exceptions. What I did manage to do is use plink  through the Process class to log into the device. Using redirected IO I even managed to print out the configuration. Unfortunately it doesn't print out in full. After a couple of lines a control line stops the output and waits for input

```
R1#show running-config  
Building configuration...  

Current configuration : 890 bytes  
!  
version 12.4  
service timestamps debug datetime msec  
service timestamps log datetime msec  
no service password-encryption  
!  
hostname R1  
!  
boot-start-marker  
boot-end-marker  
!  
enable secret 5 $1$Or0j$2.HDFSXaC9jh/KGxhyl6I1  
!  
no aaa new-model  
memory-size iomem 5  
ip cef  
!  
!  
!  
!  
no ip domain lookup  
 --More--
```

Like so. It seems like it's a console issue since I turned the feature to output without waiting on on the device. Sending anything at that moment i just like sending a command to the device so I can't actually ask for MORE output ( or at least I haven't found a way ). This may be either the console output issue ( asking whether to output more ) or the StreamWriter going full. My question is: is it possible to turn waiting OFF in a console application? If no - what would you suggest I do? Any ideas are welcome.

kravvcu

Answer (score 1):

Of course you can turn off " --More--". This command will help you (on routers and switches):

```
R1#terminal length 0
```

and this one (on Cisco ASA)

```
terminal pager 0
```

Answer (score 0):

Use a lightweight TFTP library and use that instead of console downloads?

http://www.codeproject.com/Articles/19314/A-simple-TFTP-client-using-C

If you are set on the console version, just process start a plink connection and read your config off of the process i/o.

http://www.chiark.greenend.org.uk/~sgtatham/putty/download.html